# How can you detect a parent with a nested relationship in a database using SQL?

Tags: sql, firebird, recursive-query, firebird2.1

I'm using Firebird 2.1.  There is a table name `Folders`, with the fields:

- FolderID
- ParentFolderID
- FolderName

`ParentFolderID` is -1 if it's the root folder -- otherwise it contains the parent folder's ID.

How can I find all parents (up to the root folder) of a low level node?

Do I need a recursive query? ([Firebird supports them](http://www.ibphoenix.fr/IMG/pdf/Firebird.2.1.2007.en.pdf+firebird+with+recursive&ct=clnk))

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Try an English site :) http://pabloj.blogspot.com/2008/01/new-challenges-new-synthax.html

Comment: @ypercube: Je ne comprende pas :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy (folderid, ParentFolderId, FolderName) as (
   SELECT folderid, ParentFolderId, FolderName
   FROM folders
   WHERE ParentFolderID = -1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT folderid, ParentFolderId, FolderName
   FROM folders f
     JOIN hierarchy p ON p.folderID = f.parentFolderID
)
SELECT *
FROM hierarchy
```

**Edit**: the following query will walk the hierarchy "up", finding all parents of a given folder.

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy (folderid, ParentFolderId, FolderName) as (
   SELECT folderid, ParentFolderId, FolderName
   FROM folders
   WHERE folderid = 42

   UNION ALL

   SELECT folderid, ParentFolderId, FolderName
   FROM folders f
     JOIN hierarchy p ON p.parentFolderID = f.folderID
)
SELECT *
FROM hierarchy
```

Comment: I think the query you posted returns all childs of a parent node. Do you have a query that finds all parents of a child node? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to "reverse" the starting condition and the "traversal" condition. See my edit

Comment: Thank you this works! Could you please help with one more thing: I'm using the List command to put the foldernames together in a string (Child 2 / Child 1 / Parent). How can I reverse the result of the query so it will look like: Parent / Child 1 / Child 2?

Comment: Check out this posting in the FB mailing list: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/firebird-support/message/106989